# How to get a return value from a React component function prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component:

```
const WizardView = () => {
  return (
    <Wizard finishButtonClick={() => {}} />
  );
};
```

The finishButtonClick function returns some value that I want to use and expects () => void
Is there a way to use the value that finishButtonClick returns in another function?

For example something like this:

```
anotherFunction(finishButtonClickReturnValue);
```

Comment: @CaptainMhmdrz_A This comment is not useful, better try to explain what you think OP is doing wrong

Comment: *returns some value that I want to use and expects () => void* , this seems a little contradictory, could you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you can do it like this:

```
const WizardView = () => {
  return (
    <Wizard finishButtonClick={value => anotherFunction(value)} />
  );
};
```

Or as follows if you'd prefer:

```
const WizardView = () => {
  function handleClick(value) {
    anotherFunction(value)
  }

  return (
    <Wizard finishButtonClick={handleClick} />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the return value in state and use it in another function

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const WizardView = () => {
 const[finishVal,setFinishVal]=useState()
  const finishbuttonclickfunction=()=>{
    //set the return value in state
    setFinishVal('function return value')
}
anotherFunction(finishVal){
  //you can use the return value here
}
  return (
    <Wizard finishButtonClick={(val) => finishbuttonclickfunction(val)} />
  );
};
```